# 2nd order homogenous differential equation solution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Suppose we have this differential equation :

$-\frac{2}{x^2}y(x)+\frac{d^{2}y(x)}{dx^2}=0$

One obvious function which satisfies the equation is $y(x)=x^2$

We take $x^{2}$ to be a partial solution and from it we try to find the general solution.

Let $f_{o}(x) = u(x)\cdot x^{2} $ be the full solution of the differential equation:

they by differentiating $f_{o}(x)$ we get

$f_{o}'(x) = u'(x)x^{2}+u(x)2x$

and $f_{o}''(x) = u''(x)x^{2}+2xu'(x)+2xu'(x)+2u(x)$

we substitute into the previous equation

and we get $-\frac{2}{x^{2}}u(x)x^{2}+u''(x)x^{2}+2xu'(x)+2xu'(x)+2u(x)=0\rightarrow u''(x)x^{2}+4xu'(x)=0$

Now I cannot find $u''(x)$

I tried doing the same procedure to find u(x) but the equation I get is the same with the one I have already found so I cannot continue.Help appreciated.

Comment: Substitute $u'=z$ then it's a first order DE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u''(x)x^{2}+4xu'(x)=0$$
$$ u''(x)x^{4}+4x^3u'(x)=0$$
$$(u'x^4)'=0$$
Integrate.

---

The DE you posted is Cauchy-Euler Differential Equation.
$$x^2y''-2y=0$$
$$w^2y''+2xy"-2xy'-2y=0$$
$$(x^2y')'-2(xy)'=0$$
$$x^2y'-2xy=C_1$$
$$\left (  \dfrac y{x^2}\right)'=\dfrac {C_1}{x^4}$$
Integrate.
$$y(x)=\dfrac C {x}+C_2x^2$$